# HP MSA 1000 SAN: Can I use 1 array/shelf?

Tags: storage-area-network

I'm planning some expansion on an HP MSA1000 SAN. My boss says that we need to have two separate arrays on the new enclosure, one for Bays 1-7, the other for Bays 8-14. Is there any reason that we need to do this?

My plan was to have the entire expansion shelf be 1 array, then create RAID 6 logical drives from that. I don't understand what splitting drives into separate arrays gain us. We don't have dual controllers, so there's no benefit there.

Thanks,
CC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSA1000's are pretty old and are unfortunately limited to creating only 2TB virtual-disks/LUNs - so depending on what size of disks you're using then you could easily have to build more than one virtual disk.

i.e. if you're using 300GB disks then 7 x 300 = ~2.1TB, you couldn't add an eighth drive to it, not in a usable way anyway - so having two blocks of this would mean you'd get at 2+2 TB - is that clear?

Comment: +1.  2TB is your limit. Our [partially] retired MSA has one shelf of 14 x 146GB configured as a single 1.6TB array. The second shelf is 14 x 300GB configured as one 1.6TB array and one 1.7TB array.

Comment: To be honest they're hateful things really, iirc the LUN limit is seriously low (32?) - we have ours to our dev team to mess with :)

Comment: That's clear. I was thinking I could just have one array with 3 logical drives on it. Looks like I'll need to split into 2 arrays, one with 2 LUNs, one with one. Hopefully that gets us through another year.

Comment: That's what you can do with a more modern san box yes, just not that one sorry.